# How join 2 SQL queries: SELECT from table and DELETE from another?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `users` & `rent`

How to select `name` from table `users` WHERE `unixtime` is before `2012-09-04`

**and**

delete from table `rent` WHERE `name` is from previous query.

It was something like below, but I dont know how to join it with delete query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `pstone_cuboids` 
WHERE  `last_used` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  '2012-09-04' )
```

Correct me if im wrong, does the above selects all dataes before 2012-09-03 (2nd, 1st, 31th etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DELETE FROM rent WHERE name IN (
    SELECT name FROM `pstone_cuboids` 
    WHERE `last_used` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-09-04')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your examples have different table names and column names, so this is just an interpretation:

```
DELETE r.*
FROM `rent` r JOIN `users` u ON r.name  = p.name
WHERE  r.unixtime < '2012-09-04'
```

See [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) for multiple-table deletes.